# get child table all values containing null sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

my tables look like

**parent table is like**

```
class Site(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Site"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tunnels = relationship("Tunnel", backref="site", passive_deletes=True)
```

**and my child table is like**

```
class Tunnel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Tunnel"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tunnel_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True, index=True)
    site_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("Site.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
```

and I want to get only those **Site** data which have Null value in **tunnel_id** in child table (as 1 site can have multiple tunnels so even 1 tunnel is Null out of n ) I want that site . how I can do this in efficient way .

P.s I am very beginner to flask .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want all sites, under whose referenced tunnel relationship there is at least one object for which the tunnel_id has a value of NULL. In this case, I recommend a join statement from the site table to the tunnel table, in which the referenced objects are queried using the foreignkey. To check whether the tunnel_id is NULL, you only have to combine this query with a filter.

```
Site.query.join(Tunnel).filter(Tunnel.tunnel_id.is_(None)).all()
```

If you prefer the session syntax.

```
db.session.query(Site).join(Tunnel).filter(Tunnel.tunnel_id.is_(None)).all()
```